# Restrict my Web API Core to accept HTML tag in POST request?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi, web-api-testing

I am using WebAPI Core and when I am sending some data from Postman as a POST request, it is saved to the database.

I have a requirement to restrict specific characters and HTML tags from the input at the global level in WebAPI. I have already implemented these restrictions in my front-end.

However, I don't want to use Model Validation, because I will be forced to implement it on each property.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to remove all of the tags? Or simply prevent them from being rendered as valid HTML when the data is retrieved from the database? For the latter you can look into [HtmlEncoder.Encode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.htmlencoder?view=net-5.0)

Comment: {​​​​​​​​
"ActivitiesName": "I<b>dl</b>e",
"id": 4,
"createdBy": null,
"createdDate": null,
"updatedBy": null,
"updatedDate": "2020-12-16T14:20:28.927",
"isActive": true
}​​​​​​​

you can check the above input which I am trying from PostMan. It is allowing to save the data but I want my API to validate the data. It should not allow any HTML tag.

Comment: You can use HtmlSanitizer library to encode the HTML tags, for eg. < will be converted to &lt; . if you want to show this back on your website this will come as < not &lt;.   This is how an XSS is also prevented to run script on websites rendering html

Comment: Thanks Prakash but i don't want to allow html as input in WebApi

Comment: Do you want to reject the request (400) or remove the restricted characters/HTML?

Comment: Bryan , I want remove restricted characters/ HTML...

Comment: @Incognito218 if you're looking to remove restricted tags, have you tried regex matching? you can register either a .net core filter or a middleware for that. I haven't used .net core in a while so I'm unable to give you exact code, but check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0